# Visual Studio CMake rsync file from remote to local

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, rsync

I have a Visual Studio CMake project which builds a static library on a remote Linux machine. The library is built on the remote machine and located on the remote machine's file system.
I'd like to add a post-build command which copies the library back to my local windows machine. I am fairly new to this and don't know the options I have. Is CMake's add_custom_command() in combination with rsync a path to go? If so, can someone help me building the command?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and explain where you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it's actually built into VS Studio CMake.
If you have a remote machine configuration in you CMakeSettings.json, set "remoteCopyBuildOutput": true.

Add this key and set the directory to whatever you want:
"buildRoot": "${projectDir}\out\build\${name}"

Comment: Very nice! It works!!  Thanks!!