# Visual Studio CMake copy executable file from remote to local

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm using Visual Studio to develop a Linux app using CMake. I'm able to compile using a remote Linux machine but I want, after the compilation, to have the Linux executable copied back to my local system. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73610488/visual-studio-cmake-rsync-file-from-remote-to-local) with the same question where is suggested to use "remoteCopyBuildOutput" flag inside CMakeSettings.json. However CMakeSettings.json has been deprecated and I can not find an equivalent setting for the file CMakePresets.json that have to be used now. Does someone know whether a similar  solution exists for this?